# Swapping field values (first name / other name field)

Tags: query

Our First name fields in salesforce are populated with the first letter of the first name, followed by a dot. We've done this because we use this for addressing letters / mailings. So, if we have a contact named John, the first name contains "J.", we also have a field given name that contains 'John'.

Since a week we started using Ebsta to connect salesforce with linkedin, but Ebsta searches for the full first name and can't find any results due to the way we are storing the names.

Now I'm looking for an easy way to fix this, so basically there are two options:

- appoint the 'first name' field in salesforce to use the 'given name' field
- swap the values between 'first name' & 'given name' fields.

Any ideas / tips?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a new field (InitializedName__c) and load the new field with the current FirstName field data, and then load FirstName with your GivenName field.  In the long run, you'll be better positioned for future integrations and system-changes by using the fields as designed.  You could also use a default value to generate the InitalizedName__c field based on the value of FirstName to save on data entry.

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts on how to do that in Salesforce? I'm pretty new to it.

Comment: Lots.  But if you're new, I'm hesitant to give you step-by-step instructions.  Are you an admin?  Do you have an on-staff admin?  Additionally, there are multiple steps to the process (including extraction and dataloading, report review, and evaluation of existing rules/triggers/workflows) so I would also warn you to be cautious if you plan to 'play'.

Comment: And if you need, please start here:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf

Comment: I'll have a look... we just use a simple one user system. So it's no corporate thing, just a simple CRM for our acquisition.